# How to inspect/export/serialize a (guile) Scheme environment

Tags: scheme, environment, guile

I'd like to export or replicate a scheme environment in another guile process. The algorithm I'm imagining would do something like this to serialize:

```
(map (lambda (var val) (display (quasiquote (define ,var ,val))
                       (newline))
     (get-current-environment))
```

And then I'd read/eval that on the other end.

However, while there are functions that return the current environment, they are in some internal format that I can't just `map` across. How can I "walk" the environment as the above? Alternatively, how else can I replicate an environment into another process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may decompose the so-called "current-environment" like this:

```
(define (get-current-binding-list)
        (let* ((e (current-module))  ;; assume checking current-module

               (h (struct-ref e 0))  ;; index 0 is current vars hashtable
              )
       (hash-map->list cons h)  ;; return a vars binding list
    ))
```

and you can call (get-current-binding-list) to get variables binding list in current-module.
Please note that each element in this list is a pair of symbol and variable type, say, (symbol-name . variable-type). So you may print it like this:
for a instance ,you got a var binding:

```
(define abc 5)
```

then:

```
(let ((vl (get-current-binding-list)))
      (assoc-ref vl 'abc)
      )
```

==> `#<variable 9bb5108 value: 5>`
This result is a "variable type" of variable "abc". You can get it's value with variable-ref procedure.

So you can trace all the bindings and do something ,in your code ,it's simply print var-name and var-value.

I know my answer is too brief, but I think there's enough information to help you to find more details in the manual. 
Hope this will help you.

Comment: Awesome answer. Looks like the heart of it is `(current-module)` which may be guile-only, but that's fine. I just want to understand.

Answer (score 2):

You can't really serialize Scheme environment. I don't known even it's possible to (portably) serialize continuations. Oh, and don't forget about FFIs. Ports and threads are unserializable too.

Comment: Oh yeah, I hadn't thought about ports and such. I don't think I need that for what I'm doing, though. I really just want to replicate variables and functions in another environment to support a kind of RPC.